# Problem copying and pasting in excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, copy

When "Add 2 points" is detected in "N4:N203", I need to add 2 to corresponding cell in "E4:K4".  Then copy "AB4:AB203" to "O4:O203" to "O4:O203".

```
Sub Moving_tees_add_2()
Dim PointsToAdd As Integer

    PointsToAdd = 2

        Sheets("MEMBERS1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Range("C4").Select

    Do Until ActiveCell.Row = 204

        If ActiveCell.Range("L1").Value = ("Add 2 points") Then
        If ActiveCell.Range("C1").Value <> "n/a" Then ActiveCell.Range("C1").Value = ActiveCell.Range("C1").Value + PointsToAdd
        If ActiveCell.Range("D1").Value <> "n/a" Then ActiveCell.Range("D1").Value = ActiveCell.Range("D1").Value + PointsToAdd
        If ActiveCell.Range("E1").Value <> "n/a" Then ActiveCell.Range("E1").Value = ActiveCell.Range("E1").Value + PointsToAdd
        If ActiveCell.Range("F1").Value <> "n/a" Then ActiveCell.Range("F1").Value = ActiveCell.Range("F1").Value + PointsToAdd
        If ActiveCell.Range("G1").Value <> "n/a" Then ActiveCell.Range("G1").Value = 
    ActiveCell.Range("G1").Value + PointsToAdd
        If ActiveCell.Range("H1").Value <> "n/a" Then ActiveCell.Range("H1").Value =  
    ActiveCell.Range("H1").Value + PointsToAdd
        If ActiveCell.Range("I1").Value <> "n/a" Then ActiveCell.Range("I1").Value = 
    ActiveCell.Range("I1").Value + PointsToAdd
        
        If ActiveCell.Range("C1").Value <> "n/a" Then ActiveCell.Range("Q1").Value = 
    ActiveCell.Range("Q1").Value + PointsToAdd
        If ActiveCell.Range("D1").Value <> "n/a" Then ActiveCell.Range("R1").Value = 
    ActiveCell.Range("R1").Value + PointsToAdd

    Range("AB4:AB203").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("O4:O203").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'ActiveCell.Range("A1").Select
    '
    '        Selection.ClearContents
    Range("N4:N203").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
    End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    
    Loop
```

Comment: So what's the specific problem you're having with the code you posted?

Comment: I would first start by updating your code to not use Select/Activate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: It works on the first row it finds the text on, but no subsequent rows

Comment: Because you have `Range("N4:N203").Select` right before `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select`

Comment: sorry  I don't understand how I should change it

Comment: First fix would be to not use select/activate: you get a lot of that from the macro recorder but you should try not to use it, since it's very rarely necessary to select a range to work with it.  See the link I posted above, and my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Without all the select/activate:

```vb
Sub Moving_tees_add_2()
    Dim PointsToAdd As Long, rw As Long, ws As Worksheet, c As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MEMBERS1") 'use a worksheet reference
    PointsToAdd = 2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            
    For rw = 4 To 204
        With ws.Rows(rw)
            If .Columns("N").Value = "Add 2 points" Then
                'loop over the range to be incremented
                For Each c In .Range("E1:K1,S1:T1").Cells
                    If c.Value <> "n/a" Then c.Value = c.Value + PointsToAdd
                Next c
                'you can directly assign the value from one range to another,
                '  without copy/pastespecial
                ws.Range("O4:O203").Value = ws.Range("AB4:AB203").Value
            End If
        End With
    Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: This almost works but adds a different number each time run..  need it to add 2 each time

Comment: If `PointsToAdd` is always 2 I'm not sure how that code could add a different number from that?

Comment: sometimes adds 1, 2, 3, etc

Comment: You had an extra 2 lines incrementing cells in "Q1" and "R1" - I left those out since they were'nt in your description where only columns E:K were incremented

Comment: Sorry but I can't imagine adding any number than 2.  Do you have some sample data you can share?

Comment: the 2 extras should be S and T

Comment: OK - added that S:T above

Comment: i see why.  Columns S and T are a part of the equation that calculates col O.  Without them the formula is off.  How do I also add 2 to columns S and

Comment: i see why. Columns S and T are a part of the equation that calculates col O. Without them the formula is off. How do I also add 2 to columns S and T

Comment: `For Each c In .Range("E1:K1,S1:T1").Cells` - see edit above

Comment: You nailed it!  I can't thank you enough for the code and the lesson.

Comment: You're welcome - good to hear it's working